# firebase ML kit Aesthetic photo Quality

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

For an android application i would like to check quality of the image before uploading it lets say give it a score and accept it based on this score.
might not be relevant but i did read the following:

Image Aesthetic Assessment

https://www.codementor.io/kushwahamit2016/image-aesthetic-assessment-a0a3etnhk
Google’s New AI Can Score Photos on Technical and Aesthetic Quality

https://petapixel.com/2017/12/26/googles-new-ai-can-score-photos-technical-aesthetic-quality/

Basic Image Data Analysis Using Python: Part 1

https://dzone.com/articles/image-data-analysis-using-numpy-amp-opencv

but am interested to know if there is any library ( to run on the mobile it self if not is something we could find in firebase-ml-kit or any other kit )
best regards

photo for clarification:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean resolution by quality, you can check it as follows.

```
Bitmap bmp;
//....
//load your bitmap to bmp
//....
int width, height;
width = bmp.getWidth();
height = bmp.getHeight();
```

Comment: thank u, i mean checking the photo and give it a score based on which we can tell the user he'd rather change it ..
i added a photo to the post to show what i mean 
thank u anyway